# Getting 'Security Exception' in ASP.Net Web API GET request from a Sub Domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed a test asp.net web api application to the web but when i try to test it, it throws an exception. 
The application works locally.
Here is the orignal api link
`http://service.mobinweb.com/api`
Here is exception details
`System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed`.

**Note:**the application is deployed to a subdomain

Here is the stack trace

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetCorrelationId(HttpRequestMessage request) +0
   System.Web.Http.Tracing.TraceRecord..ctor(HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level) +190
   System.Web.Http.Tracing.SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter.Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, Action`1 traceAction) +102
   System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) +166
   System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ContentNegotiatorTracer.Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable`1 formatters) +250
   System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult`1.Execute(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T content, IContentNegotiator contentNegotiator, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable`1 formatters) +76
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, HttpConfiguration configuration) +111
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Func`2 errorCreator) +198
   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception exception) +75
   System.Web.Http.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +627
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() +233
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +60
   System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628700
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

**UPDATE:**
the local data resulted json is;

```
[{"Id":3,"Title":"title goes here","Description":"description goes here","CreatedDate":"2013-12-21T00:00:00","Date":"21/12/2013","OrderBy":1,"NavigateUrl":"www.google.com"}]
```

Comment: A stack trace and some code may help, this basically only shows that there had been an exception, not really what could possibly be causing it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, the url is working. check it online

Comment: Are you trying to access a local path? (i.e. c:\someFolder\someFile)

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio, i updated the question, u can check the local json data result

Comment: Looks like tracing is your problem, try disabling it (in web.config or the page attribute whichever you've enabled).

Answer (score 1):

The security exception means there is some problem with [trust environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493%28VS.80%29.aspx).

You can quickly verify this by setting following in web.config. But do not use this when you make the web api live. You need to set the custom permission sets when you go live.

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: i tried this but its not allowed from parent level, i guess becuase of the hosting

Comment: what should i set in originUrl="" ? like originUrl="service.mobinweb.com" ?

Comment: `This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.`

Comment: It is optional, just for testing do not set this to anything, it will be for whole web app.

Comment: Are you able to set above settings in web.config?

Comment: @Balachandra, check this url, its live for testing `http://service.mobinweb.com/`

Comment: Looks like, You need to contact your Web Server Administrator.